# What did Noether contribute to the theory of integral invariants?

Tags: mathematics

What did Emmy Noether contribute to the theory of [integral invariant](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Integral_invariant)s that wasn't already done by, e.g., Sophus Lie in his 1902 [*Über Integralinvarianten und Differentialgleichungen*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/25157)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noether was the first to, as she said in the abstract of her 1918 "[Invariant Variational Problems](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/PCZVNCHS/Noether%20-%201971%20-%20Invariant%20variation%20problems.pdf)" paper ([*The Noether Theorems*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6355) p. 3), formulate

> a combination of the methods of the formal calculus of variations and of Lie’s theory of groups.

She says

> For those differential equations that arise from
>   variational problems, the statements that can be formulated are much more precise
>   than for the arbitrary differential equations that are invariant under a group, which
>   are the subject of Lie’s researches.

and recognized that

> For certain groups and variational problems this combination is not new